# Insert from another database with select option and where both database table id's equal

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert table data from my old database. Id's equal in both database table and selecting specific column. Here is my databases.

Old database:sch -> old table:product

```
(id, tag, url) 
(13, red, aaa.html)
(14, red, bbb.html)
...
(100, red, zzz.html)
```

---

New database:orgin -> new table:user

```
(url, oldid) 
(null, 13)
(null, 14)
...
(null, 100)
```

There are 135 tags same values in old database table and old ids inserted to new database table. I want to insert all url from old database table with tag columns 'red' and old database table 'id' equals to new database table 'oldid'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a `JOIN`ed update :

```
UPDATE orgin.user u
INNER JOIN sch.product p ON p.tag = 'red' AND p.id = u.oldid
SET u.url = p.url
```

This query will pull out every user whose `oldid` exists in table `product` with a red `tag`, and set its `url` to the corresponding value in `product`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i get an error " #1146 - 'user.user' doesn't exist " what can be wrong ? There are two different databases and their table.

Comment: @Emre : ok, what are the names of old database/table, and of new database/table ? Basically you should replace `product` with `old_database.product` and `user` with `new_database.user`.

Comment: I edited my post. There are database and table names.

Comment: Thank you for edit but there is no error and affected rows '0'. So no data updated to the orgin database's user table.
Edit: Sorry mate i tried again it works fine :) Thank you so much.

Comment: So the query is running fine. You might want to check your data. Does `SELECT * FROM sch.product WHERE tag = 'red'` returns some results ? If yes, then pick one of the returned `id` and run : `SELECT * from orgin.user WHERE oldid = <thisid>`, does it return something ?